# How to map jsonb input parameter in Postgresql stored procedure in java

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, jsonb

Function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_json(
    p_name character varying,
    p_content jsonb)
```

Following java call ends with SQL Exception about need of param cast...

```
PreparedStatement ps = helper.prepareStatement(conn, "SELECT * FROM insert_json(?, ?)");
            ps.setString(1, name);

            PGobject pgo = new PGobject();
            pgo.setType("jsonb");
            pgo.setValue(content);

            ps.setObject(2, pgo);
```

PostgreSQL 9.4

Answer (score 1):

Yes you must create PGobject and insert, but with some changes:

First:

```
PGobject pgo = new PGobject();
pgo.setType("jsonb");
pgo.setValue(content);
```

Second:

```
jdbcTemplate.update("SELECT yourFunction(?, ?)",
        new Object[] {text, pgo},
        new int[] {Types.VARCHAR, Types.OTHER });
```